# Is there a more efficient way for performing multiple nested for loops in matlab?

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a small logical array (`A`) of size 256x256x256 with an unknown shape of ones somewhere in the array. Also there is a smaller double array (`se`) of size 13x13x13. In se there is a defined cube of logical ones in the middle of the array (`se`).

I need to run over every logical element in `A` and for each logical one in `A` the smaller array `se` needs to add its ones to `A`. Meaning dilating the shape of `A` by `se`.

Here is what I got so far. It works, but is of very poor performance in respect to speed.

Does anyone has a suggestion of how to speed up this coding task?

```
[p, q, r] = size(se);
[m, n, o] = size(A);

temp = zeros(m, n, o);
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:n
        for k = 1:o
            if img_g(i, j, k) == 1
                for s = 1:p
                    for t = 1:q
                        for u = 1:r
                            if se(s, t, u) == 1
                                c = i + s;
                                d = j + t;
                                e = k + u;
                                temp(c, d, e) = 1;
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
B = temp;
```

I am very grateful for any help and suggestions that improve my programming skills.

Comment: If that's really plain 3-dimensional dilating, and you have access to MATLAB's _Image Processing Toolbox_, then have a look at how to [dilate Points in 3D Space Using Spherical Structuring Elements](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html#bu7td82-1) for an example. Apart from that, 3-dimensional convolution (see [`convn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html)) should also work (with some subsequent steps).

Comment: There is definitely one, by applying operations on matrices instead. Now, which operation to perform? depends on what you want to do. Unfortunately, I could not understand what you want to achieve. Can you explain it in other words please?

Comment: There is no way of speeding up nested loops without changing the implementation of your code. I would also suggest you to check imdilate() from the Matlab documentation if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: I tried to avoid using the image processing toolbox. Thats why I do the dialtion myself.

Comment: Can you put in an example `A` and `se`?  Is it enough to do `A = rand(255, 255, 255); A(20:40, 20:40, 20:40) = 1;`?

Comment: A dilation with a cubic SE is separable into 3 dilations with straight line SEs, one along each of the image axes. This will speed up your computation in a fundamental way, since you will be doing a lot less comparisons. Next, each of these three 1D dilations can be implemented very efficiently using van Herke’s algorithm, leading to a constant time independent of the size of the SE (3 comparisons per output pixel). Also, this will be able to run in-place, so you won’t need the `temp` array.

Comment: Also note that you are writing out of bounds in `temp`, which leads to reallocating the array (you’ll notice it is bigger at the end of your code than at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

dependent on the processor you're using, you can at least use "parfor" for the outer loop (first loop).
this enables parallel computing and accelerates your performance by the number of physical kernels your processor got.

Comment: In general a suggestion one could cosider, but it won't work with my code structure and my changes of ```temp```.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this does what you're asking (as I'm not completely clear on what your code does), but perhaps the methodology will give some inspiration.

I've not generated a "logical" `A`, but a random one, and I've set a cube inside equal to 1.  Similar for `se`.  I use [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to get arrays corresponding to the indices, and use a `mask` of logical indexing.  (perhaps my `mask` is what you have for `A` in the first place?)

```matlab
A = rand(255,255,255);
A(40:50, 23:33, 80:100) = 1;
mask = (A==1);

[I,J,K] = meshgrid(1:255);

se = rand(13,13,13);
se(4:6, 3:7, 2:8) = 1;
se_mask = (se==1);

[se_I, se_J, se_K] = meshgrid(1:13);
```

Here I'm assuming that the cube in `A` is far enough from any edge (say 13 spaces) so we wont get `c`, `d` or `e` larger than 255.

I've flattened `mask` into a row vector so `find` gives a single index `ii` we can use to refer to any point in `A`, then the original `i`,`j` and `k` indices are in `I(ii)`, `J(ii)`, and `K(ii)` respectively.  Similar for `se_I` etc.

```matlab
temp = zeros(255, 255, 255);
for ii=find(mask(:).')
  for jj=find(se_mask(:).')
    c = I(ii) + se_I(jj);
    d = J(ii) + se_J(jj);
    e = K(ii) + se_K(jj);
    temp(c,d,e) = 1;
  end % for
end % for
```

The matrices `I`, `J`, `K`, `se_I`, `se_J` and `se_K` are regular, so if making/storing these becomes a bottleneck you can write functions to replace them.  Matrix `temp` might be very sparse depending on the size of your cubes of ones, so you could look into using [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html).

I've not compared the timings against your solution.